# How to pass data to AsyncFileUpload (client) events?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I am creating an ASP.NET website and I'm using the AJAX Control Toolkit "AsyncFileUpload" control, I just want to pass a value to the `onclientuploadcomplete` client event, and I want to do that after saving the file from the `UploadedComplete` server event.

Here's my current `AsyncFileUpload`:

```
 <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload2" runat="server" CssClass="fileupload" onclientuploadstarted="uploadStarted" 
                                UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" Width="221px" 
                                onclientuploaderror="upload_error" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                onclientuploadcomplete="done_uploading" />
```

And her's my current Javascript code:

```
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   
   var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>";

    function done_uploading(THE_VALUE) {
         //TODO: ALERT THE_VALUE
    }

    function uploadStarted(sender, args) {

        var file = args.get_fileName();

        var extensions = "7z";

        if (!new RegExp("(" + extensions + ")$").test(file)) {
            throw (new Error());
        } else {
           // show_loading();
        }
    }

    function upload_error() {

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - Just replace your delegate with this

```
function upload_error (sender, args)
{
   //Print : args.get_fileName() 

   //Print also :args.get_errorMessage()

   document.getElementById('JustSampleForPrint').innerText = args.get_errorMessage();
}
```

Nota : Add this element JustSampleForPrint, in order to print inside.

Comment: How about custom data, to pass it from the server event to the client event? Is it possible?

Comment: I suggest you to modify your sign of method, in order to capture error. it's possible but it's not adapted in this case, you can modify your html render with c# with <% %> tag, or generate js script with RegisterStartup ...

Comment: Hi Aghilias, Actually I tried before to modify a hidden field from the server event and retrieve its value from the client event later, but the hidden field is always null, I will try now RegisteStartup to see if it would works on a normal HTML element. Thank you.

Comment: @Mohamed You can use this : <% YourFunctionWhoReturnValue() %>  in your value of control